# Can I show one div, hide all others, based on clicking its assigned button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems to be a common question, however when I check the answers, they're all different.

I have a row of five links. Each has a corresponding div below.  When I click a links, I want its div to display and all others to hide.

Here's some code I came across that seems to be on the right track:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('rel');
   $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

But if I use "a" without a destination, clicking the link takes me to the top of the page.  I just want the divs below to show or hide...

Can I use "button" or "div" instead of "a"?  If so, what would I use instead of "rel"?

Sorry for the noob question.  I just can't seem to make any of the solutions I've found here work for my site.  What's the simplest way to do this?

Here's some HTML that definitely works with the jquery script above:

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("#" + target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" rel="week_3">Week 3</a>
<a href="" rel="week_4">Week 4</a>
<div>
  <div id="week_3" style="display: none">[..xz.]</div>
  <div id="week_4" style="display: none">[...]</div>
</div>
```

However if my `href=""`, clicking that link bounces me up to the top of my page for some reason.  So I'd rather use a clickable div or a button rather than a hotlink.  In which case, what can I use in the script instead of "rel"?

Comment: please share the html

Comment: `rel` and `id` are same?

Comment: *Semantically* you should not be using an `a` as it's not a link.  You *should* be using a button.  Just give it a data attribute and use that `<button data-rel="week_4">Week 4</button>..<div id="week_4"...` `$(this).data("rel")`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you only need to prevent the default behaviour by adding `e.preventDefault();`

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("#" + target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" rel="week_3">Week 3</a>

<a href="#" rel="week_4">Week 4</a>

<div>
  <div id="week_3" style="display: none">[..xz.]</div>
  <div id="week_4" style="display: none">[...]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below values on your href.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Anchor</a>
```

Here is the complete explanation for javascript:void(0)

> The JavaScript void operator evaluates the given expression and then
>   returns a value of undefined. https://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_void_0.cfm

Comment: You *can*, but it's very '90s... :)

Comment: Agree @freedomn-m

Comment: @freedomn-m whilst it may be 90's, is there anything wrong with this approach??

Answer (score 0):

[Target attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) does not suitable for divs it is only for windows or iframes. Also, hyperlink should has `href` attribute otherwise it will be an anchor or placeholder link in HTML5 specifications.

You may use any conjugation attributes between the link and its div such as link title will be div id.

Example:

```
<a href="#" title="div1">Show DIV 1</a>
  <a href="#" title="div2">Show DIV 2</a>
  <a href="#" title="div3">Show DIV 3</a>

<div id="div1" class="linked-div" style="display: none">&nbsp;One</div>
<div id="div2" class="linked-div" style="display: none">&nbsp;Two</div>
  <div id="div3" class="linked-div" style="display: none">&nbsp;Three</div>
<script>
$("a").click(function(){
 divId = $(this).attr("title");
  $(".linked-div").each(function(){
    if ($(this) == $("#"+divId)){
      $(this).show()
    }
    else{
      $(this).hide()
    }
  })
 $("#"+divId).show();
})
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/becoqutapi/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `href="javascript:"` or `href="#"` instead of leaving the attribute empty. `href=""` tells the browser to reload the current page that you are in, which is why it bounces you to the top of the page.

You can also use `<button>` or `<div>`, the effect will not be very different from using `<a>`. You can also use `rel` if you are using `<button>` or `<div>`. In fact, it is arguably better to use `rel` on `<button>` and `<div>` because the attribute does not have any functional purpose in those tags. On the contrary, `<a>` uses the `rel` attribute to [specify a few things to browsers](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp).